# not able to create AVD to execute appium scripts

Tags: android, android-studio, appium, android-virtual-device

I am trying to use android virtual device as emulator for my appium scripts but while creating AVD I am not getting any option to select under CPU drop down

I have installed android studio bundle and have installed system images for Android 7.1.1. Below are images for same:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see the message in the CPU drop down saying "***No System image installed for this target***".

Just install the remaining unchecked System Images(Except Android TV and Android Wear) for Android 7.1.1 and try. It should work.